# Converting Strings into Excel Friendly Format

Tags: python, csv

I have a string of text. The string has multiple newline characters in it. I want to create a csv that includes this string so I can import it into excel. However because of this I believe I have to convert all the new lines to carriage returns and wrap the text in quotes.

However when trying to convert a small amount of text I get the follow results:

**Before**

```
>>> abc = "\nA\nB\nC\nD\nE\nF\nG\n\n"
>>> print abc

A
B
C
D
E
F
G
```

**After**

```
>>> xyz = abc.replace('\n','\r')
>>> xyz
'\rA\rB\rC\rD\rE\rF\rG\r\r'
>>> print xyz
G
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

Use [the Python `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv), which already knows how to do this.

```
import csv
with open('xyz.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
  w = csv.writer(outfile)
  w.writerow(['a\nb\nc'])
```

After running this, you can inspect the output (the `-A`, on GNU cat, shows a representation of nonprintable characters):

```
$ cat -A xyz.csv 
"a$
b$
c"^M$
```

Note that you can also use `cat -A` to see why your prior implementation appeared to be doing the wrong thing.

Comment: Thanks, when I use the above code to create a CSV it still places all the text into seperate cells (??)

Comment: @felix001: This works. You are probably not following it carefully enough. Note that the `writerow` method accepts a sequence, which it splits up into separate cells. Here, Charles has given it a sequence with only one element, and that one element is a string which happens to include embedded newlines. If he had passed in a string directly (not within a list), then the *string itself* would have been the sequence that gets split up into cells (each containing one character).

Answer (score 3):

Try writing that string to a file and looking at it in a text editor.

Your console is interpreting a carriage return as "return to beginning of line", so the A prints, then the B prints where the A was, etc, until G is printed where the F was.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
xyz = abc.replace('\n','\r\n')
```